# Name of the coordinate system

Tags: gazebo-11

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hey,

I tried to get the name of the coordinate system of the world from the docu, but so far I found nothing.
What is the (global) coordinate system called in the documentation in gazebo?
Also if you can send me the link to the docu page.

Thank you for your help

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/26504/name-of-the-coordinate-system/) by [morrac](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/36133/morrac/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 57 on 2021-02-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

If you are not targeting a model link, you may leave any related field empty. This will reference the world frame.

If you are using the ROS API, then it also lets you have "world" or "map" specified as well.

https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs/blob/kinetic-devel/gazebo_ros/src/gazebo_ros_api_plugin.cpp#L725

---

Originally posted by [nlamprian](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/8391/nlamprian/) with karma: 833 on 2021-02-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2